# Possesive pronomen + eins..?

Tags: possessive-pronoun, indefinite-pronoun

Could someone explain the grammar of the amalgation of possesive pronouns with eins? For example consider the word 'euereins' source: [example](https://www.lingq.com/en/learn-german-online/translate/de/euereins/).

Comment: Hiding the topic in a link is not recommended practice and unlikely to increase number of answers.

Comment: oops, I didn't mean to 'hide' it. I've put in post body now. I read the word when I was reading a story book.

Comment: Good point @CarstenS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I seldom encounter another combination than *unsereiner*, which is defined in [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/unsereiner) as indefinite pronoun and as colloquial with the meaning *sombody like us*. The singular form *meinereiner* (somebody like me) is even more colloquial but sometimes used in conversation, likely due to its internal repetition.

I can't address the historic part, but the used *einen* is already the indefinite pronoun. DWDS just mentions that the first part is no genitive form.

Comment: I think DWDS doesn't mean "unser" is not genitive, but that "unsereiner" has no genitive. E.g. *"Autos unsereiner" is wrong. Also note that "unsereins" ist much more frequent than "unsereiner" according to DWDS.